# How to append zero with condition

Tags: excel

Would be great help if you can help me below:

`1082010 01022010  2082005  112011 0112016  011220155`

are the values.

Here I want to append single zero in beginning in each values which are less than 8 digit, and for any values which is less than 8 digit but already has zero in beginning no changes required. ( Here it is case with 5th value that is 0112016) no changes required in 8 and 9 digit values too. Can anyone give macro to do that.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please share your efforts !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```
=IF(AND(LEN(A1)<8,LEFT(A1,1)<>"0"),"0"&A1,A1)
```

The screenshot shows the original data in row 1 and the results of the formula in row 2. The cells where the formula changed the value from row 1 are highlighted in red.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please take the time to mark the answer as explained in the [Tour]. That's how you can say "thank you" around here.